# How to extract time from string in Python

Tags: python-3.x, time, python-re

I am developing a program and I am trying to find the time in the string.
Time format should be military format. like,

```
10:30 or 23:20
```

An example:

```
a = 'set reminder for 10:45'
b = 'set reminder for 17:50'
```

And the results should be like that,

```
a = '10:45'
b = '17:50'
```

How to achieve these results? Using `re` doesn't make sense to me, since if we get before and after this `:` sign and there is another `:` sign, wouldn't we get an error?

Comment: `re` is the obvious solution (`\b\d?\d:\d\d\b`), so could you explain why it doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: How do we use re? If we get before and after this ':' sign and there is another ':' sign, wouldn't we get an error?

Comment: Or do you want to store the time in a [time object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time)?

Comment: @CherryDT Please share as an answer so I can give you vote.

Comment: @Ronald No buddy.

Comment: Don't take it personally. People are free to vote questions and answers how they want, based on what they feel is a useful question/answer or not, that is, useful to future readers. I don't know the reason in this particular case. People are not obliged to comment a reason, in fact there are arguments made _against_ doing so.

Comment: Only if you get several downvotes, you can assume something is wrong, but usually this comes together with some comments or with closing your question, and then there is a closure reason that explains what you need to change to get it reopened.

Comment: @Yağmur Baskın: ok, then regex is the obviously the way to go. If your strings vary more than what you've posted, you may consider posting some more variations in order to get the regex more powerful.

Comment: @YağmurBaskın for your information: I have edited your question (which is perfectly normal and shouldn't be considered rude on this platform), to include the information that you posted in comments (since comments are ephemeral here and should be used for temporary discussion, editing the question is used to persist newly added info), to clarify the title slightly and to remove the "thanks" - I know it was polite from you but here we consider these formalities unnecessary fluff. Again please don't take it personally - and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thanks,  looks better like that. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use `re` here:

```py
>>> re.search(r'\b\d?\d:\d\d\b', 'set reminder for 10:45').group(0)
'10:45'
```

The regex used here works [the following way](https://www.debuggex.com/r/VFRPdE6Wg71PtzDR):

- `\b` matches a word boundary (to avoid matching `abc12:10` or `1234:56`)
- `\d` matches a digit (tens of hours), `?` makes that match optional (since there may be only one digit for the hour)
- `\d` matches a digit (ones of hours)
- `:` matches a colon
- `\d` matches a digit (tens of minutes)
- `\d` matches a digit (ones of minutes)
- `\b` matches a word boundary (to avoid matching `12:10abc` or `12:3456`)